# ZIP file contents read by spacific sequence

Tags: php

I am working in php, I want to read from zip file having some text files inside like:

```
while($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {    
    $TableName = strstr(zip_entry_name($zip_entry), '.', true);
}
```

It gives me table name in this sequence, like:

```
1 : BPBrick
2 : BPCust
3 : BPProd
6 : BPStock <---- Notice these lines
5 : BPTran  <---- 
4 : BPValue
```

But I want to read it with my own sequence, below is the desired sequence:

```
1 : BPBrick
2 : BPCust
3 : BPProd
6 : BPTran <------ These lines reversed
5 : BPStock <-----
4 : BPValue
```

How it can be possible, I have tried to put in array like:

```
while($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {
    incoming_array[] = $zip_entry;
}
```

and then fetching from this array. Problem is,

```
while($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {    
}
  `
```

doesn't work after above array. My problem is:

HOW TO STORE TEXT FILES IN ARRAY AND CALL READ FUNCTION AFTER THAT?

Comment: Your question is unclear for me, just to clarify you want to store zip inner filenames in some array with your own sequence and then read them one by one ? or you want to store in array text content of that files

Comment: I want to store zip inner filenames in some array with your own sequence and then read them one by one in that sequence..plz help

Comment: And what is requirement for that sequence ? alphabetic or ? because i see from you example `BPStock` comes before `BPTran` which is alphabetically correct and somehow you need to have `BPTran` before `BPStock` what is logic for that sequance ?

Comment: actually i want to insert data first in BPTran Table, and then i want to use it . BPStock must be on after BPTran

Answer (score 0):

Ok this code snippet can help you to sort your array with that logic

```
// Your array with name of tables initially read from your zip 
$tableNameArr = ... 

var_dump($tableNameArr); // to make sure data read from zip properly 

// Store here items in this format `key` should be after `value`
// E.G. if `BPStock` should be after `BPTran` in your case then
$afterItemsArr = array('BPStock' => 'BPTran', .. other values.. );

foreach($afterItemsArr as $key => $value){

    $key_index = array_search( $key, $tableNameArr);
    $value_index = array_search( $value, $tableNameArr);

    // if value(BPTran) index is more then index of key(BPStock)
    // then replacing their places in $tableNameArr
    if($value_index > $key_index){
       $c = $tableNameArr[$value_index];
       $tableNameArr[$value_index] = $tableNameArr[$key_index];
       $tableNameArr[$key_index] = $c;
    }
}

var_dump($tableNameArr); // to make sure data is ok
```